# ASP: FileSystemObject from Javascript to ASP

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, filesystems

So I have this piece of code that saves some data into a log file.

```
function WriteToFile(data) {
    var currentdate = new Date(); 
    var datetime = "Time: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/" + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ " + currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var a = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\logs\\log.txt", 8);
    a.WriteLine(datetime);
    a.WriteLine(data + "\n");
    a.Close();
 }
```

In this case I call this function everytime certain functions are called so the `data` parameter would be something like `testFunction(parameter1,parameter2)` that way it will save in the log file, the time the function was called and the parameters that were used. Locally it works fine, but when I send it to production in the server it does not work. I understand that this is possible by using ASP but I have no experience with it. I've done some googling and I've found some information but I have had no luck when it comes to implementing this. I was trying to translate the above code to ASP.

So I have an HTML file with a bunch of textfields and buttons and I want to know at what time the button was clicked and which parameters were used (or textfields inside of the fieldset)
Here is an example (there are more buttons in the page but just so you have an idea)

[image: Picture1]

I got this link **http://bit.ly/15iI8Fd** but I don't understand exactly how to implement it doing what I'm doing using ASP and not javascript.

How could I do this?

Comment: So which is it: asp.net or asp-classic? The question is tagged both ways and it makes a world of difference.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn If it can be done both ways, I don't really care, I just want to achieve this

Comment: asp vs asp.net is like night and day. If you don't know which you are using yet, you need to do some other work before coming to Stack Overflow. Until there, your question has as many answers as there are programmers and is off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

This is your code translated into server side vbscript for classic ASP

```
<% function WriteToFile(data)
dim fso, a, datetime
datetime = "Time:" & Now()
set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set a=fs.OpenTextFile("C:\logs\log.txt", 8)
a.WriteLine(datetime)
a.WriteLine(data & vbcrlf)
a.Close 
end function %>
```

If you don't like the datetime format that the Now() function gives you you should be able to find a way to alter it through Google.

You could also try declaring Javascript as your page language and using your existing code server side

Comment: Thank you John! So how do I call this function using javascript onclick event or directly from each JS function so I know the exact parameters that were used?

Comment: If you're doing it server side then you'd want to use a request object - eg WriteToFile(Request("Id")&","&Request("Username")) - assuming those are the names of the fields in your "Crear" form

Comment: If you have a "POST" form you can use Request.Form rather than just Request.  If it's a "GET" form you can use Request.Querystring

Comment: I don't have a form. So I would just call it like `onclick="WriteToFile(Request("Id")&","&Request("Username"))"` ?

Comment: No, you need to submit your data via a form, and because it's server side code the page needs to be reloaded so that the function is executed while the page is loading.  I suggest you do a bit of reading about the asp request object - http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_request.asp